# Nuxt open link into modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I'm building a [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/) application that has a list of products and clicking on one of them open a dedicated page of the product. It is working fine.

Structure is:

```
/pages/featured // directory of products
/pages/product/:id/:slug // Dedicated product page
```

Now I wish to add a new feature:

- I wish to keep the dedicated page of the product if clicked from a page that is not the directory of the products or if people land directly on it;
- I wish to open an almost full-screen dialog of the product on top of the directory if, obviously, clicked from the directory;
- Keep the routing change on dialogs.

A nice example of what I wish to achieve is the photo directory of [Youpic](https://youpic.com/explore).

A list of "products", visible entirely in a dialog with its internal navigation.

I'm looking at the various [nuxt-routing](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/) and [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html#nested-named-views) documentations to try developing it but I'm still far away from the solution.

This small portion of the code I see here looks pretty similar at what I need but I don't understand how should I correctly implement it and how to create my nuxt custom routing:

```
export default {
  router: {
    extendRoutes (routes, resolve) {
      routes.push({
        path: '/users/:id',
        components: {
          default: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/users'), // or routes[index].component
          modal: resolve(__dirname, 'components/modal.vue')
        },
        chunkNames: {
          modal: 'components/modal'
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What about adding an iframe to that modal and navigating through it?

Comment: Did you end up finding a good solution to this? I've been trying to solve the exact same problem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have built a sandbox solution for you here: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-leftpad-xj81p

### Explaining the solution:

The solution uses `beforeRouteLeave()` function from the `vue-router` which is available to your nuxt pages by default:

```
beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
  if (to.name === "product-id") {
    this.displayProductModal(to);
  } else {
    next();
  }
},
```

This function interrupts any route changes on the featured page before they happen, and if the target route is the route of the product detail (which means someone clicked on product link), it opens the modal dialog instead.

To handle the url change on opening and closing of the modal, the `window.history` object is used:

```
displayProductModal(route) {
  this.activeModal = route.params.id
  window.history.pushState({}, null, route.path)
},
hideProductModal() {
  this.activeModal = null
  window.history.pushState({}, null, this.$route.path)
}
```

Try to play around a bit, it should work exactly like the youpic example you provided.

*Note: There are no real "modals" used in the example, the whole example is as basic as possible for the sake of simplicity.*

Comment: Cheers for this example and explenation,! It is working very well! Cheers!

Comment: Works well, one minor thing, is there any hook/event when browser back button is clicked?

Comment: I got the back button issue working with [popstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event)

Answer (score 1):

I recently implemented this feature after facing nearly the same situation you are in.   At least in my case, I was really overthinking it.

All that I did was take the single resource page  (/pages/product/:id/:slug in your case) and have it be a modal by default.   I am using vuetify and v-dialog is a modal.  The nuxt project hierarchy didn't change.  Your equivalent would be the slug.vue page.

```
<template>
<v-dialog v-model="drawer" fullscreen hide-overlay transition="dialog-bottom-transition">
    <v-card height="100vh">
        <div class="flex">
            <v-toolbar dark color="primary darken-2">
                <v-btn icon dark @click="close">
                    <v-icon>close</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
                <v-toolbar-title>{{member.alias}}</v-toolbar-title>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-toolbar-items>
                    <v-btn text nuxt :to="`/members/${member.id}/notes`">Notes</v-btn>
                    <v-btn text nuxt :to="`/members/${member.id}/edit`">Edit</v-btn>
                    <v-btn text nuxt :to="`/members/${member.id}/payments`">Payments</v-btn>

                </v-toolbar-items>
            </v-toolbar>
            <v-row no-gutters>
            </v-row>
        </div>
    </v-card>
</v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
watchQuery: ["id"],
transition(to, from) {
    if (!from) {
        return "slide-left";
    }
    return +to.query.id < +from.query.id ? "slide-right" : "slide-left";
},
data() {
    return {
        id: this.$route.params.id,
        drawer: true
    };
},
fetch({ store, params }) {
    store.commit("members/active", params.id);
},
computed: {
    member: {
        get() {
            return this.$store.getters["members/active"];
        },
        set(member) {
            this.$store.commit("members/update", {
                id: member.id,
                member: member
            });
        }
    }
},
methods: {
    async close() {
        await this.$nuxt.$router.go(-1);
        this.drawer = false;
    }
}
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try very soon and let you know!

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working as I do expect... the `/featured` page lose all contents, I wish to emulate exactly what Youpic did for their gallery. Thanks!

Comment: If this is the contents of the :slug, it should have no impact at all on the contents of featured.

Answer (score 1):

What I have an understanding of your requirement is looking at https://youpic.com/explore is that you want `https://www.example.com/featured (directory of products)` route and there on click of product you want open dialog which will be full screen with the route as `https://www.example.com/product/:id/:slug (Details page)`.

please correct me if I am wrong!!

Now you can achieve this with 2 way

1) On click of the each product(i.e.`https://www.example.com/featured (directory of products)` route) use `nuxt-link` with redirect to `https://www.example.com/product/:id/:slug (Details page)` route

2) On click of the each product(i.e.`https://www.example.com/featured (directory of products)` route) manually update the route with `router.push` and open dialog

Now, if we see https://youpic.com/explore and let's take this as `Nuxt` code structure will be `pages/explore` where they manually update route with `router.push` to https://youpic.com/image/16660875/steffi-by-fs22photography but when you share/take this `URL(https://youpic.com/image/16660875/steffi-by-fs22photography)` and try to open that so in `Nuxt code structure` you have to maintain `pages/image/:id/:slug` which will actually a page if you directly see go to https://youpic.com/image/16660875/steffi-by-fs22photography Page you can see.

Hope this will help you!!

If you have any doubts we can discuss more!!

Comment: You got the point but I would like to see some example because like that, to be honest, I don't know what should I do... I already use `nuxt-link` for each product from the featured page, but it land on that page... I need the modal to be on top of the explore page, with its URL changed. Exactly like youpic/explore. It would be nice to have an example on how I should configure these 2 pages and routing... Thanks!

Comment: Do you have your code online working?? Or can you add code online tools??