# Nuxt: Open component/page as modal with dedicated url like dribble.com

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

In my Nuxt application I have a list of properties, and on click I would like to open the corresponding property page `(/properties/_slug.vue)` as a modal in front of whatever page the user was on.

**[dribble.com](https://dribble.com) is an exact example of the functionality I'm trying to recreate.**

If a property link is clicked on from `/`, the url should be `/properties/slug-of-prop`, and when I hit the close button or back button, it should close the modal and return the url to what it was before click. In addition, I'd like to be able to visit `localhost:3000/properties/slug-of-prop` and have it show me the `properties` list with the modal in front of it.

My file structure is:

```
/pages
--index.vue
--/properties
----index.vue
----_slug.vue
```

I have tried the solution listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60793173/2232797 but, it doesn't remove the modal on hitting the back button. In addition, I've also attempted to implement this vue.js solution [here](https://dev.to/charleswritescode/how-to-display-a-route-as-a-modal-in-vue-js-iid) by using middleware to add `showModal` as a parameter of my route, but it's using `router-view` I am having a really hard time understanding how it works.

Here is what my `/properties/index.vue` looks like:

```
<template>
  <section class="container-fluid">
    <!-- property cards -->
    <div class="info-row scroll-row border-bottom">
      <nuxt-link
        v-for="property in properties"
        :key="property"
        :to="`properties/${property.uid}`"
        tag="div"
      >
        {{ property.uid }}
      </nuxt-link>
    </div>
    <div v-if="showModal" class="modal-route">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <router-view></router-view>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { store } from '@/store/index.js'

export default {
  computed: {
    showModal() {
      return store.showModal
    },
  },
.....
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? I am obviously pretty new at this, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an easier way to handle this without all the fuss of middleware or manually messing with the history.

I've created a CodeSandbox project here, and tried to keep it as similar to your setup as possible: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-knuth-rolrn.  Check it out, it has everything I'm about to explain in a working example.

The first thing you should do is check out [Nuxt Child](https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-nuxt-child/).  It's basically `router-view`, but designed specifically for Nuxt.

```
<div class="info-row scroll-row border-bottom"
  @click.prevent.stop
>
  <nuxt-link
    v-for="property in properties"
    :key="property.uid"
    :to="`/properties/${property.uid}`"
    tag="div"
    style="text-style: underline"
  >{{ property.uid }}</nuxt-link>
</div>
<div v-if="showModal" class="modal-route">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <nuxt-child></nuxt-child>
  </div>
</div>
```

Couple notes here:

- I've added `@click.prevent.stop` to cancel the click event from propagating, which can trigger the cards listeners
- I've prefixed the `to` with a /.  When missing, the route will just be appended to whatever route is already in the address bar.
- I've switched your `key` to the `property.uid`, since that should be unique.

One very important thing for nuxt child to work: The folder containing the children elements **must** be the same name as the parent filename.  In this example, I used `index.vue` and `index/`.  Index.vue is the parent, and everything inside `/index` is considered a child route that can be rendered.

This gives you a folder structure like this:

```
/pages
  index.vue
  /index
    /properties
      _slug.vue
```

The next thing that's changed is the `showModal` method.  I'm using `this.$route.matched.length` to determine *if* there's a child component.

```
computed: {
    showModal() {
      return this.$route.matched.length;
    }
}
```

The slug itself is the most complicated piece here, just due to the way that I implemented the example listeners.  However, I'm sure you have some other ways of handling this.

```
<template>
  <div ref="cardContainer" style="padding: 20px; border: 1px solid black" >I'm a card for property {{this.$route.params.slug }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    // Attach listeners for handling clicks outside the card, while preventing propagation
    // of clicks in the cards
    this.$refs.cardContainer.addEventListener('click', this.stopPropagation)  
    document.body.addEventListener('click', this.closeModal)
  },

  beforeDestroy() {
    // Make sure to cleanup!
    this.$refs.cardContainer.removeEventListener('click', this.stopPropagation)  
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.closeModal)
  },

  methods: {
    // Prevent clicking inside the card from triggering the closeModal
    stopPropagation(e) {
       e.stopPropagation()
    },
    closeModal() {
      // You can also do this.$router.push('/') to preserve the history
      this.$router.replace('/')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This was SO helpful, you have no idea. Thanks much for you time!

Comment: upvoted! is it possible to do this without the modal content being a child? i have a separate /login route that needs to be displayed as a child of /

Comment: If you want to have a `/login` route displayed with all the content on `/`, you could place your `login.vue` page inside the `index` folder from the example.  If you open a new question with more specifics on what you need I'd be happy to help!

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-morning-k66c1?file=/pages/index/login.vue

Comment: Thanks so much for this, it was really useful!

I've got a follow up question sorry and I think it may just be my particular setup but while it shows a URL in the address bar if I try and go to that directly it doesn't work.

Now I think it might be because I'm using a static site and thus that route isn't generated on build but just wanted to see if anyone else has a solution for this?

Comment: @user2659895 You're absolutely right, but there are a couple "Nuxt" workarounds.  Assuming SEO is a primary requirement, you could either statically render with the dynamic pages you need, or you could switch to server side rendering.  If SEO is not a priority, you can instead handle "404's" within the Vue app, and dynamically load whatever data you need.  All 3 of these are pretty off topic to the original post, so I'd recommend you open a new issue.  Feel free to tag me!

Comment: @HMilbradt thanks so much for the kind offer, I really appreciate it. I'll give it a go myself first to see if I can figure it out, if not I'll start a new issue about it. Thanks again!

(your response also made me realise I really needed to sort out my username!)

Comment: @HMilbradt I just wanted to confirm I got it working. Required some changes to what I'd done as at first it was showing the overlay but not the modal but eventually figured out it was down to how/when I was getting the details that had been passed in. Thanks again for your original answer and for pushing me in the right direction with this :)

Comment: @HMilbradt thank you very much for the sandbox, correctme if I am wrong, if you wanted this /login route to be accessible from every page, you would have to duplicate the children section inside router no?

Comment: @PirateApp Yes, that's correct, although I wouldn't suggest using this pattern for auth.  You would end up with URLs like /products/login, or /orders/register, for every single page you had this on (assuming I'm understanding you correctly).  I would instead use something like a globally registered Auth component, and trigger it opening and closing based on events and auth status.