# Nuxt Popup Overlay and routing

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, vue-router

I'm working on a project where I need to **display courses in a popup that overlays the current page, and that the URL changes.**

If I access the URL directly, I would arrive at a separate page that contains the training.

I don't see how I can get one page to overlay another, or a component to have a route.

A site that contains the effect I am looking for: https://area17.com/
The projects open in popus, and their URL is accessible separately.

Here is my current structure:

```
pages/
--| index.vue
--| /formation/
-----| _slug.vue
```

**index.vue**

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(date, index) in orderedDates">
    <NuxtLink :to="`/formation/${slug}`">{{date.name}}</NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';

  export default {
    computed: {
      ...mapState(['dates']),
      orderedDates: function () {
        return _.orderBy(this.dates, 'ACF.date')
      }
    },

    created() {
      this.getDates();
    },

    methods: {
      ...mapActions(['getDates']),
    },
  }

</script>
```

**/formation/_slug.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="absolute">
    {{product}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapState } from "vuex";


  export default {
    name: '_slug',
    data() {
      return {
        slug: this.$route.params.slug,
      }
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapState(["dates"]),
      product() {
        return this.dates.find(el => el.slug === this.slug);
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

How to overlay a page on another page? How to route the whole thing properly?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I found this question and it seem's to be working : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60692255/nuxt-open-link-into-modal