# Nuxt open link into modal everywhere and can be close modal by pressing the browser back button

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I have a profile page with the path "/profile", a product page with the path "/products", and a product detail page with the path "/products/id". On the profile page, I have a Nuxt link element with a path to navigate to the product detail page as "/products/1". When clicking on it, Nuxt will normally replace the view of the profile page with the view of the product detail page. However, I want the layout of the profile page to remain unchanged, and the layout of the product detail page to be displayed in a dialog, while also changing the URL to "products/1"

[Nuxt open link into modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60692255/nuxt-open-link-into-modal?newreg=ede5c51a0f6944ed8ed4b78c342576ad)

```
beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
  if (to.name === "product-id") {
    this.displayProductModal(to);
  } else {
    next();
  }
},
methods: {
  displayProductModal(route) {
    this.activeModal = route.params.id
    window.history.pushState({}, null, route.path)
  },
  hideProductModal() {
    this.activeModal = null
    window.history.pushState({}, null, this.$route.path)
  }
}
```

I followed this guide, and it seems to work fine. However, I noticed that using the window.history variable instead of $router causes an issue. When I click the back button in the browser, I can't listen for URL changes to close the dialog. I believe that there might be a different approach where I should use the $router variable instead of window.history.